# Can sub folder point to different hosting provider www.domain.com/subfolder

Tags: domains, dns, cname, dns-servers

I have a situation where we need to point a sub domain to a different hosting provider.

The main website `www.mainwebsite.example` is being hosted with HostingProvider1 and now we have another application `www.example.com` which is hosted with HostingProvider2.  We want this application to be accessible only via 
`www.mainwebsite.example/application`

I am not sure how this can be done at DNS level. Our main domain which is `www.mainwebsite.example` is hosted with Network Solutions, I am not sure if I can make `www.mainwebsite.example/application`  on DNS level to point to a different hosting provider.

If it was `application.mainwebsite.example` then it would be simple as I can change the `CNAME` record. But in this case the client wants `www.mainwebsite.example/application` to point to different hosting.

Not sure if this is possible only at DNS level.

Comment: Why not just redirect mainwebsite.com/application to example.com

Comment: I wish it was that easy, But requirement is from client he want subfolder to point to different hosting provider

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/155562/can-you-have-a-blog-in-a-subdirectory-hosted-on-a-different-server

Comment: It can't be done at the DNS level.   It can only be done using a reverse proxy.

Comment: I am not sure what reverse proxy is

Comment: A reverse proxy runs on your main server.   When a request comes in for that subfolder it would look up the content from some other server and re-serve it.